# Difference between show column and describe in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Is there any difference between in MYSQL:-

```
SHOW COLUMNS from XYZ;
```

AND

```
DESC XYZ;
```

Both seems to give same result

Comment: [Per the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/describe.html) `DESCRIBE` is just a shortcut for `SHOW COLUMNS`

Comment: Describe is a shortcut of SHOW COLUMNS FROM.

Comment: So, DESC is short cut of DESCRIBE and DESCRIBE is short cut for SHOW COLUMNS.. cool.. way to go mysql :)

Comment: @JackDaniel's All database engines I'm aware of have synonyms (or shorts), and MySQL is no exception. In fact, SQL itself has many too.

Comment: I understand they have shorts... but this one is short of short :)

Comment: If it is just a shortcut then why cant I use where clause with DESC? I can use it with Show column..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The source of information in situations like this is the documentation

> **[EXPLAIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html)**
>   DESCRIBE is a shortcut for SHOW COLUMNS.
>   ...
>   The DESCRIBE statement is provided for compatibility with Oracle.

Both provide means for column name pattern matching

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM users LIKE '%name';
DESC users '%name';
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2923e/2)** demo

Comment: Can i use where with DESC? Seems like where works with show columns not with desc...

Comment: @JackDaniel's No `DESC` doesn't support `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is, there is no difference between them in the way you used them.

For other types of usages, they have a bit different syntax and `SHOW COLUMNS` can be a bit easier to use when you want to specify something like a `LIKE 'pattern'` or a `WHERE expr`.

Comment: Then why have different SQL commands to get the same result ?

Comment: @PratikCJoshi If you read my answer carefully you will see that there is a difference.